# How come Arya Stark wasn't hurt by this in Game of Thrones Season 8 Episode 5?

Tags: plot-explanation, game-of-thrones

In S08E05 of Game of Thrones Sandor Clegane convinces Arya to leave the Red Keep and go home. There is a scene towards the end of the episode, right after Arya escapes the falling bell tower and ends up helping the woman and her child to escape, when Daenerys comes from the background towards them (woman, child, and Arya).

> The dragon breathes fire on them, burning everyone - but later we see Arya stand from the ashes, un-burnt, *even though she was clearly covered in fire*. She proceeds to the white horse, which she rides out of King's Landing.

Why was she not burnt?

> Does this have something to do with her killing the Night King?

For evidence that she was hit by the fire: [Just look at this.](https://twitter.com/i/status/1127794448048513024) She has clearly been covered in flames.

Comment: I guess she had a high quality kit of plot armour with her... We'll see in S8E6

Comment: I think Arya is "round a corner" so out of the full blast of the flames so only gets licked by them. Don't have time to check though.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot in other scenes, corners didn't protect though :S

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot thats what I thought too, but after watching it again I noticed the wall behind her was burnt to a higher level which means she was completely covered..watch it again

Comment: She kept repeating "Not today" throughout her journey out of Kings Landing & the Lord of Light repeatedly saved her. That is canon

Comment: There was some debate in our house as to whether she even survived, or whether that last scene was a 'ghostly farewell'. We decided there wasn't enough evidence to come to any rational conclusion & we'll find out next week.

Comment: @KharoBangdo are you sure with that "Not today"? I didn't catch that. However i kinda had the impression that she was resurrect like Jon

Comment: @marstato exactly, that's the case, if she was not supposed to die she shouldn't have been shown running with the people around, 100% of whom died one way or another.

Comment: @KharoBangdo We have *zero* reason to believe the Lord of Light actually exists or helped Arya in any way, so no, that's definitely not canon.

Comment: What am I meant to see in your link? I thought it would be her, covered in flames, as the description suggests but it is in fact her there, not covered in flames? Is my phone / Twitter being weird?

Comment: Unfortunately, I think the real answer is going to be that Miguel Sapochnik loves to fake kill people.  i.e. Jon Snow in the Battle of the Bastards, Sam like 5 times plus Jon Snow, Arya, Jaime, Brienne and pretty much any other named character in the Battle of Winterfell.

Comment: Obviously it's because she's a rogue and her Evasion kicked in for those fire breath attacks

Comment: Arya kind of forgot that fire burns.

Comment: Reminder to everyone: answer in answers, not in comments - and support your claims with evidence. (I like @Nacht's D&D reference, though :P )

Comment: Covered in flames or just covered in the ash, the fallout from the fire?

Comment: Why did you remove the spoiler markup?

Comment: It appeared blank first time so I removed the '!'... I just read about it I will fix that now...sorry

Answer (score 57, accepted):

> We see Arya stand from the ashes un-burnt even though she was clearly covered in fire... why was she not burnt, does this have something to do with her killing the Night king?

### It was simply the camera angle that made her appear to be on fire.

By the time Drogon's flames reached the wall Arya was behind, she was already a couple feet past the corner and nearly lying on the ground. The licks of the flame that *appear* to be on Arya are *really* a few feet in front of her; it's simply the camera angle that made it seem like they were on her.

Consider the following series of images:

[image: Sequence of images]

> but just look at [this]..she was clearly covered in flames

If we zoom in on the wall Arya was behind, although the wall is blackened higher up, it's clearly untarnished by the flames towards the bottom (where Arya was lying down).

[image: Wall behind Arya]

Having the flames *appear* to be on Arya was probably even done on purpose in order to add suspense. Since the scene immediately cuts away from Arya right after this happens, for several minutes everyone is left wondering if she got burnt and/or possibly even died.

Comment: She was also fortunate to be hiding behind a wall that wasn't constructed of Explodium

Comment: @Mohirl Yeah, it was probably made of the same material of the rock Jon hid behind of in episode 3

Comment: Reminds me of https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ConvectionSchmonvection

Comment: ⎨Indeed, what an admirable degree of attention to detail. Nothing less than we have come to expect in this season of GoT.⎬

Comment: (@KonradRudolph - Is it just me or are there some random odd characters in your comment?)

Comment: @BruceWayne I tried adding “sarcastises” but I had to make do with what Unicode offers me. Depending on the fonts you have installed they may look wonky. Put more directly, this answer is obviously nonsense: There’s no such detail. Arya survived despite being engulfed by dragon fire because the directors want her to survive, end of story.

Answer (score 113):

> we see Arya stand from the ashes un-burnt even though she was clearly covered in fire

You don't see Arya clearly covered in fire. You see Arya *obscured by* fire, i.e. there is fire between Arya and the camera.

Arya ducked behind a wall (IIRC of an alley). Flames tend to flow (I can't speak to real life but this is how they are shown in GOT), and thus don't quite cut a corner that sharply.

Here's a quick (and dirty) diagram of what I mean:

[image]

The angle of the alley acts as cover. The flames that still enter the alley get pushed to the other side of the alley, away from Arya.

The camera does get engulfed in flames. Bad depth perception and reflex leads the viewer to believe that Arya is engulfed in flame, but in reality she is only obscured.

We can argue that people can get burns from being close to a source of heat without touching it (and a dragon's flame would certainly be hot enough), but that's not how it's usually portrayed on TV and in movies. Media tends to stick to the "you burn yourself by touching it" idea, which is not really realistic, but fairly commonly used and accepted as a trope.

Comment: ""you burn yourself by touching it" idea, which is not really realistic, but fairly commonly used and accepted as a trope" - https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ConvectionSchmonvection

Comment: The dragon fire here in particular also seems to come with enormous amounts of force and not just the heat from flames. Walls don't normally get knocked down by fire nearly instantly, especially note stone walls.

Comment: Some of the "exploding" or knocked over walls can be explained by trapped moisture being instantly converted to steam by the extreme heat.  But that makes it even less believable that a person could be protected by a wall since that much heat would also also explosively boil the "trapped moisture" in the person's body.

Comment: @krb: Cfr the diagram, Drogon doesn't really hit the wall Arya is hiding behind. He's torching the road, not the walls. Arya's wall is mostly protect by the east side wall of its building and the fact that the flames in the alley get pushed south due to momentum. Most damage done to this wall would then be indirect or environmental. And "you don't burn unless you touch it" applies (Convection Shmonvection, as Wolfgang pointed out and linked).

Comment: Could you re-do the diagram in classic MS Paint with wigglier lines please?